# Calculating mean temperature sphere in Matlab

Tags: matlab, temperature

I solved the temperature profile of a sphere being cooled in a gas stream with pdepe, but the assignment was to calculate at which time the average temperature of the sphere is 16C. Now I used the function `mean`, but this isn't correct for a sphere. How would one calculate the mean temperature of a sphere?

Comment: "this isn't correct for a sphere": why ?

Comment: Because the further you get away from the center, the more volume there is. So the temperature at larger radius contributes more to the average than say the temperature at the center.

Comment: There is no way we can help you without knowing the distribution of the points. You should weight the mean with the cell volumes, presumably approximated by the volume element in spherical coordinates.

Comment: It's spread evenly from 0 to 2.5e-2 meter. I thought maybe to indeed approximate it by multiplying each temperature with the volume between points and divide it by the total volume. But this is only an approximation, so I was hoping maybe there was a better way.

Comment: "It's spread evenly": in what coordinate system ? You can use some interpolation formula in the cells (trilinear to begin with) and compute the average of the interpolant.

Comment: You would probably get better help on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/) since this is an algorithm. Or maybe even [physics.stackexchange.com](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) (or some other web resource) depending on how much you konw about the problem. A guess is that you will need to use the [Heat Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation). Anyway since this is not a programming question I will flag this as of topic.

Comment: You may want to look at [this answer](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/516277-how-to-find-mean-temperature-over-area-or-volume-from-pde-solution) on Mathwork's site. I've created and answer to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Mean in spherical geometry is usually weighted by radius, the final formula for `<f>` is as follows: `f_mean = 3*trapz(r, r.^2.*f)`

Answer (score 0):

PDE toolbox functions `area()` and `volume()` might help with your case. For a 2D mesh, area() gives the area of each mesh element; one then needs to find the centroid coordinates for the element and interpolate the solution at these coordinates. Similarly, for a 3D mesh and the element volumes. The answer to [this question](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/516277-how-to-find-mean-temperature-over-area-or-volume-from-pde-solution) on Mathworks' site also showcases some code that can be used for axisymmetric geometries.